# add padding to wrapper in css Grid causes horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would add padding to the parent div so that my card inside don't stick to the screen limits , here what I have done

```
<div class="padding">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <app-character-card></app-character-card>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <app-character-card></app-character-card>    
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <app-character-card></app-character-card>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);

}
.padding {

    margin: 10px;

}
.card {

width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <app-character-card></app-character-card>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <app-character-card></app-character-card>    
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <app-character-card></app-character-card>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The padding is causing me an horizontal scroll (100% width + padding I suppose)

How can I define inner padding without having scroll ?

[image: scroll]

**Update**

I have updated my class to padding , now I get the padding not centered

[image: padding not centered]

Comment: Use `padding` instead of `margin` in `.padding`

Comment: I get new strange behaviour now (look my update)

Comment: try giving `width:100%` to `.padding` class

Comment: I get a larger width so it adds horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1):

Your code above seems to work perfectly. You'll have to provide more information to track the mistake.
But the thing that should work for almost all cases like yours is specifying the `CSS` for the `html` & `body` elements as follows:

`body, html{
   max-width: 100%;
}`

I hope that this works.

But if it doesn't then please provide a little more information as in code or something so that finding a work-around gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

In this screenshot from the Chrome Developer Tools you can see the effect of the different values. The property `margin` is used to add spacing outside the element but in your case you want to use `padding` to add it inside.

[image: Google Chrome Developer Tools]

```css
.container {
    padding: 10px;
}
```